# Rails complicated selection with order in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, mongodb, mongoid, relationship

I have:

> gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
>
> gem 'mongoid', '~> 6.1.0'

I have 3 models, related to this question.

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :author, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :status, type: String
  field :image, type: String

  has_many :histories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  def ordered_histories
    histories.order(taken_in: :desc)
  end

  def book_rating
    rating_array = likes.map { |like| like.rate.to_i }
    return 0 if rating_array.empty?
    (rating_array.sum / rating_array.size).round
  end
end

class Like
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :rate, type: Integer
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end

class History
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :taken_in, type: DateTime
  field :returned_in, type: DateTime
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**I need to get top 5 books which have the most count of likes and histories.**

As I know - mongoid not support joins. 
I thought about storeing likes_count and histories_count in Book model. But I think that it is not best way. Please help me to find better solution to get top 5 books from mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

Try the following code to get the ids of the top 5 books with most histories count. The same approach can be used for the Like class.

```
History.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group" => {
        "_id" => "$book_id",
        "histories" => {"$sum" => 1}
    }},
    {"$sort" => { "histories" => -1}},
    {"$limit" => 5 }
])
```

Comment: Hello. I tried this way, but I don't exactly understand how to get ids of top books from the returned. I have assigned returned value of this code to the variable top_books and then view in console the result. I found that result is:

Comment: #<Mongo::Collection::View::Aggregation:0x00000004d9e960 @view=#<Mongo::Collection::View:0x40695240 namespace='library_exercise_development.histories' @filter={} @options={}>, @pipeline=[{"$group"=>{"_id"=>"$book_id", "likes"=>{"$sum"=>1}}}, {"$sort"=>{"likes"=>-1}}, {"$limit"=>5}], @options={}, @cursor=#<Mongo::Cursor:0x38733420 @view=#<Mongo::Collection::View:0x40695240 namespace='library_exercise_development.histories' @filter={} @options={}>>> 
Also I have tried to iterate result and found that it contains only first book id
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5a9aabf193e60b126fd406dc'), "likes"=>2}

Comment: I read a loot of documentation, but I need to clarify how to get all 5 books ids. Please help me if you can.

Comment: How many books with history do you have in your database? Do you have a seed script or database dump with sample data so that I can restore it locally and test it?

Comment: I am sorry. I made little mistake. You was right. I have only one book with history.
But I have 2 books with likes. After I tried this way:
Like.collection.aggregate([
    {"$group" => {
        "_id" => "$book_id",
        "likes" => {"$sum" => 1}
    }},
    {"$sort" => { "likes" => -1}},
    {"$limit" => 5 }
])
I got 2 books in right order.

Comment: Have you any ideas how I can use one query to get top 5 books sorted by likes and histories at the same time? And also contain books that don't have any histories or likes if database have more than 5 books, but only one of them have likes or histories?

Comment: I found another way how to do it and posted it. If you have time, please check it. Also now I can't provide database dump.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to make it works. 
I have add counter_cash to model Like and History:

```
class Like
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :rate, type: Integer
  belongs_to :book, counter_cache: :likes_count
  belongs_to :user
end

class History
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :taken_in, type: DateTime
  field :returned_in, type: DateTime
  belongs_to :book, counter_cache: :histories_count
  belongs_to :user
end
```

After that I use one query to get top 5 books which have the most count of likes and histories:

```
@top_books = Book.all.order_by(likes_count: :desc, histories_count: :desc).limit(5)
```

I think it is one of possible way to do this. May be it help somebody. Tell me please, if I made any mistakes.